# What is the right way to pack a payload with Python3's pwntools

Tags: python, pwntools

On the [tutorial by Megabeets, *"A journey into Radare 2 – Part 2: Exploitation"*](https://www.megabeets.net/a-journey-into-radare-2-part-2/), he shows an example of how to create a payload with Python2

```
# Initial payload
payload  =  "A"*140 # padding
ropchain =  p32(puts_plt)
ropchain += p32(entry_point)
ropchain += p32(puts_got)

payload = payload + ropchain
```

How would that get ported to Python3? `p32` is a 32bit integer. Python3 uses `bytes()` instead of strings. What's the right way to do this?

`python3-pwntools`'s docs show that there are some [payload helpers](https://python3-pwntools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fmtstr.html). But, I couldn't get them to work. Worse yet, those helpers [were available in Python2 as well](http://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/fmtstr.html), but not used (not sure why).

How would I write Megabeet's example using `python3-pwntools`?

Comment: Thank you was looking for 1-2 hours about this. usually I do all my stuff on ruby/C/GO but was following an example that uses pwntools so was ignorant about this b'a'*100 etc switch was trying with str() but broke pwntools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is a programming question and not an RE question. Anyway, you simply need to tell python to treat your payload as bytes by adding the bytes-literal `b` before the `'A'*140`.

```
>>> from pwn import *
>>>
>>> puts_plt = 0x8048390
>>> puts_got = 0x804a014
>>> entry_point = 0x80483d0
>>>
>>> payload  =  b'A' * 40   # Only 40 for the example
>>> ropchain =  p32(puts_plt)
>>> ropchain += p32(entry_point)
>>> ropchain += p32(puts_got)
>>>
>>> payload = payload + ropchain
>>>
>>> print(payload)
b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x90\x83\x04\x08\xd0\x83\x04\x08\x14\xa0\x04\x08'
>>>
```

For further reading, you can read the [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings) page in the Python3 documentation.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work with your script, so I was wondering if there was more to it in python3 as I'm fairly certain I got the variables at the top correct (see this for follow up https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/19784/22669). I wasn't sure if it was as simple as using the bit literals, or if I was supposed to use the payload formatter in pwntools.